# keras"s error on different conda environment

Tags: python, keras, conda

I am working with python 3.7, win 10. I have defined a new environment using conda, unfortunately when  I activate my environment using

```
conda activate the "name of my environment"
```

I want to use my last notebook when I run in a cell Keras import commands

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras import metrics
import keras.backend as K
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
```

I faced with the error regarding Keras or TensorFlow

the error is so:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~\Anaconda3\envs\envc\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\Anaconda3\envs\envc\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d5531b57a346> in <module>
----> 1 from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
      2 from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
      3 from keras import metrics
      4 import keras.backend as K
      5 from keras.preprocessing import sequence

c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 
      8 # Globally-importable utils.

c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in <module>
      7 from six.moves import range
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
     10 
     11 

c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>
     87 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     88     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 89     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     90 else:
     91     # Try and load external backend.

c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in <module>
      3 from __future__ import print_function
      4 
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops as tf_ops
      7 from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages

c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 
     26 from tensorflow._api.v1 import app

c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\moha\Anaconda3\envs\envc\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\moha\Anaconda3\envs\envc\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help
```

I have tried a different solution here

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22872

does not work or faced with other erros?

do you have any easy solution to solve the issue?

I need to assert that it works on my main environment, I think it is related mostly to Keras with backend TensorFlow   ...

Comment: There is something fishy going on, as you are inside your environment, but your `tf` seems to be loaded from `c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`, which should not be checked unless you are in your base env. Can you check that you have tensorflow installed in your environment and that `PYTHONPATH` is set correctly?

Comment: I have checked via pip, I have TensorFlow on env ``` tensorflow                         1.13.1``` how can I see python path is installed correctly? I mean It works for other packages, should be set for the TensorFlow separately?

Comment: I'm guessing you followed some outdated advice at some point and manually added `C:\Users\moha\anaconda3\bin` to your `PATH`. That has been discouraged since Conda 4.4.

Comment: I have checked it, it was not in my path! I also heard that Keras transferred to tf.keras, could be related to this?  https://twitter.com/fchollet/status/1174018651449544704?s=19  @FlyingTeller

Comment: @merv  please let me know your idea

Comment: @DevML there's still not enough info. You didn't answer: "Do you have `tensorflow` installed your env?" Generally, the errors we see have to do with two different `site-packages` being used - that in **base** and **envc**. When **envc** is activated and you're in Python, all modules should load from **envc**. The fact that it doesn't indicates that you have some environment variable that is "leaking" the **base** env's location to Python. You need to search your environment variables and figure out what it is and how it got set.

Comment: thank you for the response,  as mentioned in the comments, yes, I have TensorFlow in my envc. I did find any path  like this c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages

Comment: A simple test to see if your environment is leaky: 1) activate the env 2) run `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`. If you see anything other than stuff in `~\Anaconda3\envs\envc` then you have a problem. I think the error already indicates this is the case. You need to search your environment variables (not just `PATH`) to see how it's getting in. Often it means some environment var with `PYTHON` in its name is set. I think the Windows way of searching is something like `SET | findstr /r "PYTHON"`.

Comment: ['', 'C:\\Users\\moha\\Anaconda3\\envs\\envc\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Users\\moha\\Anaconda3\\envs\\envc\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\moha\\Anaconda3\\envs\\envc\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\moha\\Anaconda3\\envs\\envc', 'C:\\Users\\moha\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages', 'c:\\users\\moha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages'

Comment: and the resit is :'C:\\Users\\moha\\Anaconda3\\envs\\envc\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\moha\\Anaconda3\\envs\\envc\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\moha\\Anaconda3\\envs\\envc\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\moha\\Anaconda3\\envs\\envc\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin'

Comment: I guess c:\\users\\moha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages' the reason of leak, but I can find it in my variable  environment , the answer of that comment is CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\Users\moha\Anaconda3\python.exe